# Managing disk in a VM

Tags: hard-drive, virtual-machine, nas, storage, zfs

I'm replacing my two old rack servers with a new one that has plenty of power to take over the functionality my current servers. The server is a 4U rack mount with 16 3.5" SAS drive bays, two 2.5" bays, a Xeon E3-1230v2 CPU and 32GB of ECC RAM.

My issue is the following. I would like to have a FreeBSD file server with ZFS managing disks. However, I need other VMs for e.g. a shell/git server, mail server etc. I'm wondering how to deal with the following issues:

1. I want ZFS to fully manage the disks, so I'm not using any hardware RAID. Should I pass the SAS controller directly to the FreeBSD system as passthrough PCI?
2. I want to maximize the reliability of the setup. On what disks should I install the hypervsor and keep server system disks?

For (2) I have the option of having a RAID setup on the SAS controller and using that as system disk to store the hypervisor as well as VM images. However, this makes PCI passthrough to the file server impossible. Another option is using the two 2.5" bays. In terms of reliability how are SSDs compared to e.g. WD RE4 disks? Would it make sense to have two SSDs in software RAID as boot disks for the hypervisor or should I just go with e.g. WD RE4 disks in a software RAID setup.

I also need to think about where to store the mails for the mail server, but this could be done over NFS between the VMs.

BTW, this is for home use, so the load is not really that big. What I'm looking for is best practices for splitting up a server.

Comment: This question is way over my pay grade, but: 1) This should probably be asked on another forum (Unix & Linux or maybe serverfault?). 2) It should probably be broken down into more than one question to reduce it's complexity. You can ask to have it migrated to another forum if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed that this should probably be migrated, but in the meantime, here is some insight for you.

Caveat: On the whole, this is not best practice for a setup using the technology you've indicated; you'd gain far more reliability and performance by running your configuration directly off of the hypervisor and either getting software RAID to manage your disks directly, or spending the money to purchase a hardware RAID card.

(Answering 2. first, for logistics)

2: You haven't specified, I'm going to assume you plan on using ESXi. An isolated mirrored set will offer the the most reliable configuration the ESXi OS. If you're concerned about resiliency/fault tolerance of the hypervisor, again I would strongly recommend against using software RAID to do this at all (ESXi doesn't play nice with most software RAID, and even if your controller is supported, you're still dealing with (at best) BIOS-based software RAID reliability and performance). If you decide to do this, ensure that your data/VM disk set is entirely independent from your hypervisor disk set, and back up your ESXi configuration frequently.

1: Once you have your hypervisor running, *assuming* ESXi supports your hardware for [Raw Device Mapping](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017704) you could then expose your SAS disks directly to your virtual BSD instance and z-pool/z-raid them as you like, exposing them via NFS to other VMs or computers in your house.

If ESXi doesn't support RDM for your hardware, the only other option would be to create virtual volumes from the ESXi hypervisor and expose them to your virtual BSD instance. Why this is a very bad idea: you're layering a software RAID filesystem on top of *virtual* partitions. If you lose your z-pool configuration, you're liable to lose the entire array because you're dealing with a physical file system (ZFS) sitting on top of a virtual filesystem (VMFS).